# Como obter resultados randômicos em SQL com diferentes SGDBs?

Tags: sql, sql-select

Me baseando nesta [pergunta existente no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19412/1518921) e querendo trazer um conteúdo interessante e útil ao SOpt faço esta pergunta:

Como obter resultados randômicos em SQL com diferentes SGDBs?

> Estou deixando uma resposta pronta, mas vou deixar aberto acaso sujam soluções melhores ou mais performáticas

Comment: Gostaria muito de saber o motivo dos downvotes, [afinal até aonde entendo](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) responder as proprias perguntas é incentivado pelos idealizados do Stack Overflow. Grato a quem explicar as motivações.

Comment: Debate sobre a pergunta: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7007/3635

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parte dos exemplos foram obtidos nesta [resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19419/1518921) do [@YaakovEllis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51/yaakov-ellis)

> Já deixo avisado que isto não foi feito testes de performance, o que provavelmente pode ser um pouco complicado se necessitar consultar muitas coisas. Pretendo realizar testes próprios e sugerir talvez maneiras diferentes.
>
> Outro detalhe, o uso de `LIMIT`, `TOP 1`, `rownum`, etc é somente para indicar que houve limitação de resultados, afinal a intenção é pegar resultados randômicos e **não apenas ordenar** de forma randômica

## MySQL

Select randômico em MySQL:

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

## PostgreSQL

Select randômico em PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1
```

## SQL Server

Select randômico em Microsoft SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 column FROM table
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

## IBM DB2

Select randômico em IBM DB2

```
SELECT column, RAND() as IDX 
FROM table 
ORDER BY IDX FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

## Oracle

Select randômico em Oracle:

```
SELECT column FROM
( SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY dbms_random.value )
WHERE rownum = 1
```

## SQLite

Select randômico em Sqlite:

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

No SQL Server, se não for precisar selecionar todas as linhas e sim apenas uma amostra das linhas e **performance** for importante, use o seguinte:

```
SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE (ABS(CAST(
  (BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) *
  RAND()) as int)) % 100) < 10
```

A ideia aqui é gerar um numero aleatório entre 0 e 99 e depois selecionar todos que são menores do que 10. Dessa forma selecionando ~10% da base.
Você pode trocar o `100` da query por outro valor se precisar pegar porções menores de 1% da base.

Usar `ORDER BY newid()` pode ser problemático por que `ORDER BY` faz com que todas as linhas da tabela sejam copiadas para o `tempdb` e isso é lento por que pode ser muito IO e se a base for muito grande, pode estourar o tempdb.