# Busca randômica não funciona

Tags: python, django

Quero fazer uma busca randômica no banco de dados, porém não ta funcionando.
Quero pegar uma frase, e mostrar na tela, ela vai ser trocada toda vez que atualizar a tela.

Minha view.py:

```
def busca_tendencia(request):
    tendencias = Frase.objects.all().order_by('?')
    return render(request, 'busca/index.html', {'tendencias': tendencias})
```

No html:

```
{{ tendencias.frase }}
```

Meu models.py

```
class Frase(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)
    frase = models.TextField()
    data = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name  = 'Frase'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Frases'
```

Quando acesso a página não retorna nada, nem erro. E a frase não aparece.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como obter resultados randômicos em SQL com diferentes SGDBs?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/294295/como-obter-resultados-rand%c3%b4micos-em-sql-com-diferentes-sgdbs)

Comment: Acho que não é duplicata @fernandosavio. Faltou o Pedro dar o contexto correto que é de uma aplicação Django e não SQL puro, ou seja, ele está usando o ORM para isso.

Comment: Tem razão @AndréDuarte. Retirei a flag, a dúvida dele me parece mais com QuerySet do que com o random em si. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendencias está retornando todos os objetos ou linhas do banco

faça assim

```
from random import randint
...
tendencias = Frase.objects.all().order_by('?').first()
#ou entao assim para pegar um registro realmente aleatorio
tendencias = Frase.objects.all().order_by('?')
registro_aleatorio = randint(1, tendencias.count())
tendencia = tendencias[registro_aleatorio]
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia,
Amigo, dependendo do banco de dados que tu estejas usando, podes colocar uma clásula no **WHERE**, que jogue o randômico no id da coluna, e dar um **TOP 1** (Sql server), **Limit 0, 1** (postgres, mysql). Assim, ele sempre vai pegar um valor aleatório de ID, e como está em TOP 1, pegará a primeira ocorrência.
Espero ter ajudado.